# composer update missing zip extension (ext-zip) on MacOS

Tags: craft3, composer, zip

When doing a `composer update` in a Craft project on MacOS Catalina, I suddenly get the following error:

```
***** requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason seems to be that either the *PHP* version of the *MacOS Catalina* update or a version installed via *brew* do not come bundled with the ext-zip extension.

You can verify that by calling `php -m` in the Terminal. You will get a list of all modules and it will not contain the word `zip`

Even if it contains the word `zip` it does not necessarily mean that *composer* has it available. This is caused by the way *ZSH* (shell on MacOS) handles the PATH variable.

In my case I used an *alias* pointing to the MAMP version of PHP (which has zip enabled), but composer was using the PHP version found in the PATH variable.

Solution for me: Since I am using *MAMP* I modified the PATH in /etc/paths to have the MAMP PHP PATH on the very beginning, e.g.

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.31/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

After that change `composer update` should work again as expected (make sure you close your Terminal first and do the update in a new Terminal window). Also `php -m` should now definitely list the *zip extension*